# For Google Sheets/Excel, how can a name/text be entered n a column, and auto-populate a different name in a separate column?

Tags: excel, function, google-sheets

I am looking to make a spreadsheet containing employee names and managers. I want to be able to enter an employee name in Column A and automatically have their manager's name populate in Column B. I

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You'll need a list of employees and their managers, and I guess you're wanting to implement a search function?

I would suggest using a vlookup function that returns a result from one column, based on an input from your search field.  If I'm way off what you're looking for please edit your post to include more information including what you've already tried.